# PayPal Custom "Buy Now" Button

Tags: php, forms, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the PayPal API at the moment to create a button, I'm using the API as I have numerous tiers available and it's easier for me to create them this way. The current code I have is:

```
$sendPayData = array(
    "METHOD" => "BMCreateButton",
    "VERSION" => "65.2",
    "USER" => "userfoo.paypal.com",
    "PWD" => "1234567890",
    "SIGNATURE" => "asf234.NotARealSignature.28rd28uhGDG09",
    "BUTTONCODE" => "ENCRYPTED",
    "BUTTONTYPE" => "BUYNOW",
    "BUTTONSUBTYPE" => "SERVICES",
    "BUTTONCOUNTRY" => "GB",
    "BUTTONIMAGE" => "reg",
    "BUYNOWTEXT" => "BUYNOW",
    "L_BUTTONVAR1" => "item_number=6500",
    "L_BUTTONVAR2" => "item_name=Up to 500 users for 6 months",
    "L_BUTTONVAR3" => "amount=60",
    "L_BUTTONVAR4" => "currency_code=GBP",
    "L_BUTTONVAR5" => "no_shipping=1",
    "L_BUTTONVAR6" => "no_note=1",
    "L_BUTTONVAR8" => "cancel_return=https://www.foo.com/Payment/Cancel",
    "L_BUTTONVAR9" => "return=https://www.foo.com/Payment/Success"
);
$payreturn=file_get_contents('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?'.http_build_query($sendPayData));
$paypalResponse = array();
parse_str($payreturn,$paypalResponse);
```

Where I can use `echo $paypalResponse['WEBSITECODE']` to show the typical "Buy Now" button, but its not displaying at all on my iPhone. It just displays a grey box?

Anyway, I would prefer to use my own styled button, not an image as PayPal uses. I know that the form comprises of 3 fields, the hidden `cmd` value, the hidden `encrypted` value and the actual image itself to submit the form.

I can create my own button, it's just I cannot get the encrypted field value from the API to insert into my own system.

I would like to know if this is the best way to solve my issues, and how to do it, or is there an alternative

Answer (score 0):

This is what PayPal uses in the button form to change the button image:

`<input type="image" src="https://yourimage.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">`

So if you use this basis you can change the button image. This is just the basic button, you will need to confirm that your image is mobile optimized.